# The critical value of an infinte sum over [0,1).

Tags: sequences-and-series, dimension-theory-analysis

Consider $f(s)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty r_i^s$ where $s\in[0,\infty)$ and $0<r_i<1$.  Under what conditions can we claim that there exists some $s$ such that $f(s)=1$.

I know that some $s$ exists in the case of a finite sum (using the facts that $f(s)$ represents a continuous strictly decreasing function over $s\in[0,\infty)$ and $f(0)\geq 1$).  However, the infinite case I think is not continuous nor strictly decreasing over $[0,\infty)$.  For example, it can be the case that $f(s)=\infty$ over some interval $[0,s_c)$ and $f(s)<\infty$ for all $s\geq s_c$. I think that $f(s)$ should become a continuous strictly decreasing function once it becomes finite.  If this is the case, another formulation of the question could be, "Under what conditions can we claim $1\leq f(s_c)\leq \infty$?"

Comment: as it converges at $s=0$ it also converges for $s > 0$, thus $\lim_{s \to \infty} f(s) = \text{#}\{ i \ | \  r_i = 1\} = K$. of course $f(s)$ is decreasing so $K$ must be $\le 1$, and as $f(s)$ doesn't converge when $s \to -\infty$  there is $\sigma$ such that $f(s)$ converges only for $s > \sigma$ : it has a pole there and clearly $\lim_{s \to \sigma^+} f(s) = +\infty$.

Comment: f(s) does not converge at s=0.  $f(0)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1=\infty$.

Comment: $f$ is indeed strictly decreasing and continuous on the interval where it is finite (which might be empty). But in the situation you mention it can be that $f(s_c) < 1$, and I don't see any way to get a useful condition giving $f(s_c) \geqslant 1$.